About the sigma algebra generated by the Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb R^n$
Let $\mathcal{H}^k$ be the $k-$dimensional Hausdorff measure on $\mathbb R^n$, with $k \in \{1, \ldots n\}$. By Carathéodory's theorem we know that there exists a sigma algebra $\mu(\mathcal{H}^k)$ of $\mathcal{H}^k-$measurable sets and it's posible to show that if $f:\mathbb R^k \to \mathbb R^n$ is Lipschitz and $A \subset \mathbb R^k$ is a Lebesgue measurable set of $\mathbb R^k$ then $f(A) \in \mu(\mathcal{H}^k)$ my questions are:
Is the converse of the last assertion true?
There exists a characterization of the sets in $\mu(\mathcal{H}^k)$ ?
What relations exist between the Lebesgue sigma algebra on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mu(\mathcal{H}^k)$?
For the third question using the identity function $I:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ which is Lipschitz, its easy to see that if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbb R^n$ then $A=I(A) \in \mu(\mathcal{H}^n)$, then in this case the Lebesgue sigma algebra is contained in $\mu(\mathcal{H}^n)$ this contention is proper?

The converse of your assertion is not true. Even if you exclude sets of zero and infinite measure, all the sets you construct are rectifiable and for $k<n$ there are measurable, purely unrectifiable sets of nonzero measure.

This is a partial answer. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathcal{H}^n$ coincides with the Lebesgue measure so $\mu(\mathcal{H}^n)$ coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets.
